# Understanding rotations of graphs about the origin

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> Suppose the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is rotated anti clockwise about
>   the origin thru $\pi/4$ . ${\bf find \; its \; new \; equation}$.

I know that if we rotate the usual coordinate xy-plane about an angle $\alpha$ anti clockwise, then the new coordinates are given by

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ - \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} $$

My question is: Rotating the hyperbola thru 45 degrees anti clockwise is it the same as to rotate the axis the same amount? IN such case then we have

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ - 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} x+y \\ y-x \end{bmatrix} $$

Now, we see that

$$ x' + y' = \sqrt{2} y $$ and $$x' - y' = \sqrt{2} x $$

Thus,

$$ x^2 - y^2 = \frac{1}{2} ((x'+y')^2 - (x'-y')^2) = 1 $$

which implies

$$ ( 2y ') ( 2x' ) = 2 \implies \boxed{ x' y' = 1/2 }$$

is this correct?

Comment: Plot the two graphs and see.